# Where to find reference about IP range of China?

Tags: ip-geolocation, country

Is there any document that's accurate about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MaxMind](http://www.maxmind.com/) seems to be the best amongst all IP database providers.

**http://www.maxmind.com/**

Answer (score 1):

The DNSBL at http://countries.nerd.dk is useful for this sort of thing. Given an IP address, you can do a DNSBL-style lookup on `cn.countries.nerd.dk` and it will answer whether or not that IP address is part of China's range.

Answer (score 1):

A quick google looking for APNIC has caused me to stumble [upon this IP to Country website](http://ip-to-country.webhosting.info/book/print/5), which has a database that may provide all you need (I've not looked at the database, just read the blurb on the site).